# Trying to center text within parameters in a full-width element

Tags: html, css, wordpress

http://www.cultpops.com

^ I'm trying to get the text in the black section of my site (Lorem ipsum...) to look like the text on http://shop.balticmill.com/ (under the FRESH AS A DAISY section). So pretty much centered but with parameters. Surely there is a simple way to do this and I am just making it more complicated than it needs to be. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just assign this CSS to the `p` element

```
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just add padding to the container it will push the text in

```
padding: 0 100px;
```